# Why does the screen refuse to lock after I installed LXDE?

Tags: unity, gnome, lxde, lock-screen

I have a computer, I think it's running GNOME (it's running whatever the default is; I have the Unity panel,)  and I installed LXDE for use on another user, but after installing LXDE, it will no longer lock the screen due to inactivity, or for any other reason.

When logging in, I have to enter my password, just like normal, but the screen *cannot* lock. Wait 5 mins (my setting, have verified this,) still unlocked. Press CTRL-ALT-L, no response. Even going to the gear and choosing "Lock Screen" has no result.

Even after deleting the second user account (just on a hunch,) the screen STILL cannot lock.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried removing `xscreensaver`?

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selecting `lightdm` then restarting.  Does that help the issue?

Comment: Aha. `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver` fixed it. (I want to keep XScreensaver installed, as that's the only working option for LXDE.) Now I just have to figure out what to add to the startup file: `gnome-screensaver --display=?` I've tried numbers, but that doesn't work. EDIT: @iSeth, I just saw your answer, and tried that. So far, logged into the primary account, all is fine - will reply with info after logging into the LXDE account.

Comment: YES! Both users can now be locked without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first, be sure GNOME Screensaver is installed (it's not really a screensaver manager, but more of just a daemon to handle locking/unlocking the screen):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Then, reconfigure LightDM to incorporate the changes (credit to [iSeth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/iseth) for the original suggestion,):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Finally, reboot. Everything will be fixed! Both LXDE and Unity/GNOME can now be locked without problems!